# jquery get form values, multiple forms

Tags: jquery, forms

I have multiple forms on the page and i need to get the values of the form that is submitted, but without specifying the form.

```
$(document).ready( function (){
 $('form').submit( function(){
       return submitForm()
 });

});
```

and in the .js file submitForm() should identify the id of the form that is submitted. How can be that done?

I get the values of the form[0], not the one that is clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what `submitForm()` does, but I assume you're somehow using `this` in it.

If so, try:

```
 $('form').submit( function(){
       return submitForm.call( this );
 });
```

Doing it this way should send the context of the form that was clicked to the `submitForm()` call.

So in `submitForm()` you can refer to the correct form using `this`, or in a jQuery object using `$(this)`.

---

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/pXwTE/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the id of each form to your submitForm function like this:

```
$j(document).ready( function (){
    $j('form').submit( function(){
       return submitForm($j(this).attr('id'));
    });

});
```

to get all of the values, depending on what you need to do with them, you can use serialize like this:

```
$j(document).ready( function (){
    $j('form').submit( function(){
       alert($j(this).serialize());
    });
});
```

or you can loop through all of the form's inputs like this:

```
$j(document).ready( function (){
    $j('form').submit( function(){
        $j(':input', this).each(function(){
           alert($j(this).val());
       });
    });
});
```

I created a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/2HRjF/1/