# How to Make Simple Looping a Different value A Form input Element With jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, codeigniter

I want to create simple looping in jquery this data , how i do?

This my code:

HTML Code:

```
<tr><td>FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER *</td><td>:</td><td>

<input type="text" onkeypress='validate(event)' name="id_server" id="id_server" value="" class="input-read-only" size="60" readonly="true">

<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>port/select_data_server" class="select"> SELECT FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER </a></td></tr>

<tr><td>PORT & CARD EQUIPMENT </td><td>:</td><td> 
   <?php 
     for ($a=1; $a<=15; $a++)
        {
   ?>



  <div id="form<?=$a?>">    <form>
      PORT <?=$a?> : <input type="text" name="form1_input1" id="form<?=$a?>_input1" class="input-read-only" value="<?= $port?>"
  /><br><br> 
      CARD <?=$a?> : <input type="text" name="form1_input2" id="form<?=$a?>_input2"  class="input-read-only" value="<?=
  $card_equipment?>" /><br><br>    <input type="button" value="SAVE
  DATA" name="save" id="save<?=$a?>" class="btn-kirim-login" /><br><br> 
      </form>            </div>

    <?php  
      }

    ?> 
  </td>
    </tr>

  <tr><td>HOSTNAME CONNECTION & PORT  * </td><td>:</td><td>
  <input type="text" onkeypress='validate(event)' name="id_connection" id="id_connection" value="<?php echo $id_connection; ?>" class="input-read-only" size="60"  >

 <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>port/select_data_connection" class="select"> SELECT CONNECTION </a></td></tr>


</table>

<input type="hidden" name="stts" value="<?php echo $stts; ?>" id="stts">
```

And this Javascript / Jquery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form2").hide(); // hides form2 and form3 elements on document load
    $("#form3").hide();
    $("#form4").hide();
    $("#form5").hide();
    $("#form6").hide();
    $("#form7").hide();
    $("#form8").hide();
    $("#form9").hide();
    $("#form10").hide();
    $("#form11").hide();
    $("#form12").hide();
    $("#form13").hide();
    $("#form14").hide();
    $("#form15").hide(); 
    $("#form16").hide();
    $("#form17").hide();
    $("#form18").hide();
    $("#form19").hide();
    $("#form20").hide();
    $("#form21").hide();
    $("#form22").hide();
    $("#form23").hide();
    $("#form24").hide();
    $("#form25").hide();
    $("#form26").hide();
    $("#form27").hide();
    $("#form28").hide();
    $("#form29").hide();
    $("#form30").hide();



    $("#save1").click(function() {

        var stts         =  $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server    =  $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input1  =  $("#form1_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2  =  $("#form1_input2").val();
        var id_port      =  $("#id_port").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

            else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   


            $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts, id_port:id_port },
               function(data){

                    if (id_port == ''){

                    $("#form2").show(); 

                    }else
                    {

                        alert('UPDATE SUCCESS');

                    }

                   $("#save1").hide();  


        });
    }); 


      $("#save2").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server   =   $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val();
        var form_input1 =   $("#form2_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 =   $("#form2_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }                   




            $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form3").show();   
                    $("#save2").hide(); 


        });
    });


      $("#save3").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server   =   $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val();
       var form_input1 = $("#form3_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form3_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                    else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           


             $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form4").show();
                    $("#save3").hide(); 


        });
    });


      $("#save4").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val();
        var form_input1 = $("#form4_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form4_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           


             $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form5").show(); 
                    $("#save4").hide(); 


        });
    });

      $("#save5").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val();
        var form_input1 = $("#form5_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form5_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           


            $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form6").show();   
                    $("#save5").hide(); 


        });
    });



      $("#save6").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val();
       var form_input1 = $("#form6_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form6_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }
                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           


             $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form7").show();    
                    $("#save6").hide(); 


        });
    });


      $("#save7").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val();
       var form_input1 = $("#form7_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form7_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           


            $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form8").show(); 
                    $("#save7").hide(); 


        });
    });

      $("#save8").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val();       
       var form_input1 = $("#form8_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form8_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           


            $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form9").show(); 
                    $("#save8").hide(); 


        });
    });



      $("#save9").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val();
        var form_input1 = $("#form9_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form9_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   


                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           

            $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form10").show();  
                    $("#save9").hide(); 


        });
    });

      $("#save10").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val();
        var form_input1 = $("#form10_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form10_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           


            $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form11").show();   
                    $("#save10").hide(); 


        });
    });

      $("#save11").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
var id_connection    =  $("#id_connection").val();       
       var form_input1 = $("#form11_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form11_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           


            $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form12").show();   
                    $("#save11").hide(); 


        });
    });

      $("#save12").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
       var id_connection     =  $("#id_connection").val();
       var form_input1 = $("#form12_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form12_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }
                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           


            $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form13").show();   
                    $("#save12").hide(); 


        });
    });

      $("#save13").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
       var id_connection     =  $("#id_connection").val();
       var form_input1 = $("#form13_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form13_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           

             $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form14").show();   
                    $("#save13").hide(); 


        });
    });


      $("#save14").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
       var id_connection     =  $("#id_connection").val();
       var form_input1 = $("#form14_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form14_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           

            $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 

                   $("#form15").show();    
                    $("#save14").hide(); 


        });
    });

      $("#save15").click(function() {

        var stts        =   $("#stts").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_server =     $("#id_server").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var id_connection   =   $("#id_connection").val();
        var form_input1 = $("#form15_input1").val(); // retrieve values from input
        var form_input2 = $("#form15_input2").val();

        if (id_server == '')
                {
                    alert('FIRST HOSTNAME SERVER REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }

                else if (id_connection == '')
                {
                    alert('HOSTNAME CONNECTION REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }   

                else if (form_input1 == '')
                {
                    alert('PORT REQUIRED');

                return false;
                }           


             $.post("<?=base_url()?>port/save", { id_server: id_server, id_connection: id_connection, form_input1:form_input1, form_input2:form_input2, stts: stts },
               function(data){ 


                   $("#form16").show(); 
                   $("#save15").hide(); 

        });
    });

});

</script>
```

I think my javascript / jquery code not good, how to repair it?

Comment: I didn't understand you...

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop should do it (I'm assuming that you would like to hide them, your question isn't clear):

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++)  
    {  
        $('#form'+i).hide();  
    }
```

Comment: thanks, The form is the hide the form is good, but how with looping save1, save2, save3, and other, in save the attribut/element its diferent sir, how to the loop?!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do, maybe that will help you:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300918/jquery-get-form-values-multiple-forms)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to use jquery you can loop through every form element with the .each method.

Something like this....

```
$('form').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, The form is the hide the form is good, but how with looping save1, save2, save3, and other, in save the attribut/element its diferent sir, how to the loop?! –

Answer (score 0):

if u know the exact no ie like 30, as kumar told u can use below script

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++)  
    {  
        $('#form'+i).hide();  
    }
```